# Process Lines Not Containing String And Output Line Below Matched Line Too

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

I have a good idea of what I can do here, using `grep -v '^--'` and `grep -A 1`, however I think I might need to use awk to match instead.

I have data that looks like this:

```
Random text line 1
--Data1
Random text line 2
--Data2
Random text line 3  
--Data3
Random text line 4  
--Data4
Random text line 5  
--Data5
```

The thing is, I need to run a command - let's call it `command1` on all lines NOT starting with '--' and capture the output along with the line below it.

So the three commands I want to combine are:

`grep -v '^--' file.txt | command1 > text-output`

`grep -A 1 [not sure] > --data-below-text`

I could probably do this by storing variables in a `while read line; do` type of command and then store and echo variables. However, I feel like there might be an easier way that is more efficient way to get the following:

```
Random text line 1, text-output, --Data1
Random text line 2, text-output, --Data2
Random text line 3, text-output, --Data3
Random text line 4, text-output, --Data4
Random text line 5, text-output, --Data5
```

Of course, if using variables is the only way, I'm open to doing that as well. I just wanted to make sure since I know variables can get dicey if I decide to use the code in parallel down the road. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to run command1 against every single line individually or as a whole?

Comment: Only on the lines not starting with '--' or in other words, all of the random text lines.  It is a bit tricky because I need to process the random text line, capture the output and the 'data' line below it :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a way:

```
command_wrapper(){
  in=$(cat -)
  one=$(echo "$in" | head -n1)
  two=$(echo "$in" | tail -n1)
  result=$(echo "$one" | command1)
  echo "$one, $result, $two"
}

grep -A1 -v '^--' file.txt | command_wrapper
```

here's another way:

```
textlines=$(grep -v '^--' file.txt)
results=$(echo "$textlines" | command1)
datalines=$(grep '^--' file.txt)
paste <(echo "$textlines") <(echo "$results") <(echo "$datalines") |
  tr '\t' ',' > output.txt
```

Comment: Hey Webb, second one works for me. I just added double quotes on the variables. I guess there was no way to do it without variables. Thanks for the help. I wouldn't have thought of paste on my own. Please upvote if you get a second.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way in awk that should do what you're after..

```
$ cat yourcommand 
echo "printing : $@"

:~/test/awk$ awk '!/^--/ { cmd = "./yourcommand "$0 ; cmd | getline outvar ; print outvar  } /^--/ { print }' 1
printing : Random text line 1
--Data1
printing : Random text line 2
--Data2
printing : Random text line 3
--Data3
printing : Random text line 4
--Data4
printing : Random text line 5
--Data5
```

We match all lines not beginning with -- and pass the output of that line to './yourcommand' - which in my case, just prepends 'printing :' to the line - but you should be able to replace with your own input command.

awks getline then stores the output in outvar, which we then print.  Lines starting with -- print as normal.

edit: getline only gets the next line.  Let me know if you have more lines to extract and I should be able to make it give you the rest of them.

Comment: Hey LineDash, this isn't working for me. I get a syntax error as it tries to read the output as a command too.

Comment: Can you give me the output you're getting and exactly what command you're running.